# Application time

Tags: asp.net

I need to show the application time based on the user side usage..

Pls guide me ...

Comment: Based on the user the time must be shown in the application..May be the user from US,India etc...Time must be based on the user

Comment: sorry .. My own web application

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) in javascript:

```
<div id="date"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = date;
</script>
```